# Error when trying to create a maskig policy: "Unsupported feature 'MASKING POLICY"

Tags: masking

I get the following error when trying to create a masking policy. Below is the screenshot of the Snowflake sql command and error.
Thank you
Yoram
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is only available with Enterprise Edition of Snowflake. Which edition are you running?

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for you response.
I did switch to Enterprise edition and know it works.
Thank you

Comment: Please could you tick my answer as correct? Thanks